# Stirling number bounds and polynomials and the Lambert $W$ function

Tags: co.combinatorics, polynomials, stirling-numbers

Let $s(n,k)$ be the (signed) Stirling numbers of the first kind. The polynomials
$$L_n(x)=\sum_{j=1}^ns(n,n+1-j)\dfrac{x^j}{j!}$$
enter in the asymptotic expansion of the Lambert $W$ function, see for instance Comtet, Advanced Combinatorics. They have a large number of interesting properties which I will include in a forthcoming arXiv paper. I have two types of questions.

1. By far the most important: can one give a reasonably simple upper bound for $L_n(x)$ in terms
   of $n$ and $x$ ? What I know: from the recursion for $s(n,k)$ it is immediate to deduce that
   $$|s(n,k)|\le 2^n n!/k!\;.$$ There are probably better (simple) bounds. If we keep a bound of this shape, it seems experimentally that $2^n$ can be replaced by $1.6^n$. Is this true ?
   In any case, using the above bound we deduce that $|L_n(x)|\le 2^n(1+|x|)^n$, but this seems
   far from optimal. For instance, I would expect something like $O(|x|^{n+\epsilon})$.
2. The polynomials $L_n(x)$ seem to be real-rooted (an older post proves this with $1/j!$
   replaced by $\binom{n}{j}$, but I am not sure the proof applies), and since the $s(n,k)$ alternate in sign, if true the roots are all nonnegative. Assuming this, the largest root
   seems to be $n+H_n+a/n+b/n^2+\cdots$, with $H_n$ the $n$th Harmonic sum, and $a$, $b$, etc...
   constants that I can heuristically and numerically compute to hundreds of decimals. This may give a strong hint towards a proof. Thus 3 questions here: are all the roots real, is the
   asymptotic for the largest root correct, and what is the constant $a$ (I have tried all sorts
   of combinations of Euler's and Stieltjes constants, to no avail) ?

P.S.

$$a=-4.84699097000782072187215332815747517998393619354729731953$$

Comment: A rather sharp upper bound for the Stirling numbers of the first kind is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3831483/130022)

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, if I am not mistaken this improves the $2^n$ to $e^{n/2}=1.65^n$.